# How to find occurrences of a pair in a multimap

Tags: c++, data-structures, iterator, multimap

I have been trying to write a program that finds the occurrences of a pair in a multimap. So far I am thinking of using multimap::equal_range.

For example, if my multimap is {(BO, MA), (CL, SC), (DA, TX), (FL, MI), (FL, MI), (MI, FL), (OR, FL)} and I search for all occurrences of (FL, MI) in the multimap, then my program should ideally return two iterators, pointing to the 3rd and 5th elements. I can then subtract the two iterators to find the number of occurrences of the pair. However, multimap::equal_range only checks if a key is equivalent to a single value.

Is there a way to use multimap::equal_range to indicate the range of iterators pointing to the pairs with the same key and the same value of the target pair? Or is there an existing method that I can use? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you're searching for a filter view (in ranges library).

Comment: Or simply `set<pair<>>`

Comment: There must not be such a "range". The entries with the same key in a multimap has no specified order so it can not be guaranteed that the ones with the same value form a contiguous block, they couls be intermitted with other values.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I want a method that can find the count with the same time complexity of multimap::equal_range. Also, I have to use multimap because there are duplicate keys.

Comment: @gerum If there is no range, then are there good ways of finding the number of occurrences of a pair in a multimap?

Comment: @zxcvbnm Using equal range to find the matching keys and then iterate through that range and check the value manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned>>` instead. You then get 2 fast lookups and the count without iterating.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

int main(void) {
    // your original looks something like this:
    std::multimap<std::string, std::string> m{
        {"BO", "MA"}, {"CL", "SC"}, {"DA", "TX"}, {"FL", "MI"}, {"BO", "MA"},
        {"FL", "OR"}, {"FL", "MI"}, {"MI", "FL"}, {"OR", "FL"}};

    // my suggested map:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned>> m2;

    // transform your original map to my suggested map:    
    for(auto&[k, v]: m) ++m2[k][v];

    // lookup:
    std::cout << m2["FL"]["MI"] << '\n'; // prints 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Why does my original multimap need to transformed into an unordered map?

Comment: @zxcvbnm That's just in order to be able to provide the fast lookup and to get the exact answer directly. In real code, you would not need your map in between. You could just populate my version directly.

Comment: Does transforming it into a map also work?

Comment: @zxcvbnm Yes, you can replace the two `unodered_map`s with `map`s, but I think you'll find them a tad slower in most cases.